# How can i find different of this sql 2 rows

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to count sum of this after minus please help me

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
MINUS
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 t1 
JOIN customers c ON t1.number = t2.number;
```

Comment: What does `count sum` mean here?

Comment: sorry, i means count the row of this

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what `count sum after minus` means. Als inclue the code you tried thusfar and explain what kind of data is in the database.

Comment: Do you really have three tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is :

```
select count(*) from (
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
MINUS
SELECT *
FROM table2 t1 
JOIN customers c ON t1.number = t2.number
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using CTE

```
With cte as (SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
MINUS
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 t1 
JOIN customers c ON t1.number = t2.number)

Select count(*) from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you really want:

```
select count(*)
from (select number
      from table1
      minus
      select number
      from customers
     ) t;
```

It seems really odd that you would have two tables (`table1` and `table2` in your question) with exactly the same columns.

In addition, this does something useful, which is to count the number of `number`s in `table1` that are not customers.